# After doing all what I can, there is still error "Could not find OpenCV Library - 2.4.9.apk" in Android for OpenCV

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, google-glass

To develop a Google Glass project, I need to use OpenCV in Eclipse. I have already added OpenCV Library-2.4.9 in "Projects" in "Java Build Path" as well as added it in "Android",but when I run the project, the console just says "Could not find OpenCV Library - 2.4.9.apk!". I really don't know what I should do next.

Comment: Is the error when compiling or when launching the compiled APK on a device/emulator?

Comment: When launching the compiled APK on a device, the error invokes.

Comment: That was what I assumed when I made my answer below, have you installed OpenCV Manager from the PlayStore?

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever partially implemented OpenCV before I decided to solve my problem with an alternate approach, but I remember that in order for OpenCV to work you need to either install OpenCV Manager from the Play Store or side load it onto your device.  When you initialize OpenCV in your app it will launch an intent to OpenCV Manager which if it hasn't already will download the appropriate library for your device which your app will utilize.

If you haven't already, installing OpenCV Manager on your device should fix your issue.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.opencv.engine&hl=en

It is also possible that a appropriate library does not exist for your device and that is why you are seeing this error.  I have not done any work with Glass, so I don't know if that would be the case.